# base_global_planner doesn't update in planner_frequency

Tags: ros, navigation, base-global-planner, move-base, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### environment

- OS: ubuntu 14.04 on an x64, with kernel 4.2.0-42-generic
- ROS: indigo
- package: ros-indigo-navigation:amd64/trusty 1.12.14-0trusty-20180110-202207-0800

#### config

- base_global_planner: "navfn/NavfnROS"
- base_local_planner: "base_local_planner/TrajectoryPlannerROS"
- planner_frequency: 0.5

### Problem

When navigation package is upgraded to 1.12.14 from 1.12.13, global planner doesn't update in planner_frequency.
It seems that the package is well-working at 1.12.13 in the same configuration. Is it problem of 1.12.14?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282799/base_global_planner-doesn%27t-update-in-planner_frequency./) by [hwata](https://answers.ros.org/users/33710/hwata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-02-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-15**:
If you feel this is a regression, it might make sense to report it over at the `navigation` issue tracker.

As you mention `1.12.13` did run as expected, see [this comparison](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/compare/1.12.13...1.12.14) for the differences with `1.12.14`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a known issue that has been fixed in more recent versions. https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/issues/523

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2018-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0